# How extract text from a picture to an excel sheet using Tesseract-OCR

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am still new to Python and Tesseract and I have problems trying to extract the text from an image with a table ( shown in the picture ) into an excel file. 
I followed the tutorial from [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/) and it extracted the text and print it in the console.
I want to extract the text and save the output as an excel file with tables and rows same as that in the picture. How can I do it?
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Tesseract can't do it automatically, you have to parse the output you get and then build manually your table.

Comment: Thanks @check-emee. Please how can I do that? is there a tutorial for it? Or I will be very happy if you can give me the codes that can do that.
Remember, I am still new to Python